# AutoCAD 2016 .NET API area of a House

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

i am new to AutoCAD .NET API, i want to implement a command that calculate area of
a house. can anyone tell how can i implement it using c#

regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start with AutoCAD programming, check www.autodesk.com/myfirstautocadplugin

But I must say that AutoCAD doesn't understand the concept of 'house' as we do, it contains only lines that we read as a house (or anything else).

Revit understand it better, there are clear concepts of walls, rooms, spaces, etc.

**EDITED**

Here is a C# sample sum the total area of closed polylines (2D lightweight)

```
[CommandMethod("countPlineArea")]
public static void CmdCountPlineArea()
{
  double totalArea = 0.0;

  Database db = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
  using (Transaction trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
  {
    BlockTableRecord currentSpace = trans.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
    foreach(ObjectId entId in currentSpace)
    {
      if (entId.ObjectClass != RXClass.GetClass(typeof(Polyline))) continue;
      Polyline pline = trans.GetObject(entId, OpenMode.ForRead) as Polyline;
      if (!pline.Closed) continue; // no area
      totalArea += pline.Area;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. i have read the tutorials on www.autodesk.com/myfirstautocadplugin and got some insight. please share me any additional resource & free plugins. i want to read the drawing file, identify each object types( like polylines ) & calculate the total area.

Comment: great, get the full training at http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad2016_dot_net_training.zip and check the blog http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/